# Problems with CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am designing a WebApi with MVC.NET to be consumed by an AngularJS front end.  However I have some problems with CORS when the user tries to register.

So in my Web.Config I have the following:-

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, TOKEN" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

which works fine for the login screen, ie the user logs in correctly to the system. However, when I try to register a new user, I am getting the following error:-

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:45668//api/Account//Register. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

So in the WebConfigApi.cs, I include the following code:-

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Which throws the following error when registering a user:-

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:45668//api/Account//Register. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

If I remove the web.config CustomHeaders, the registration works fine, however then the login throws a CORS error.

How can I go about this and have one centralized CORS authentication?

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: `http://localhost:45668//api/Account//Register` I can see two double slashes here. Either is a typo or your destination URL is wrong.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma amended that but still getting the same error

Comment: Mention the port number in -> new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost", "*", "*"); And in the web.config, <customHeaders> are not required.

Answer (score 0):

> There is not need to set custom header in web config. you can enable
>   CORS by following code.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:45668//api/Account//Register", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Comment: my twitter handler is : @mohitdagar80

Comment: and where do I put the EnableCors for the login?  I already had something like that in the AccountController.............[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost", headers: "*", methods: "*")]